# Embed links work on new page creation, not on edit

Tags: embed

When using the below code, I am able to see the embed youtube video when inserting it into a new page, but when I go to edit an existing page with the same code, the embed does not work.

This recently happened to me when upgrading from version 5.9 to 6.2.

```
<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Überblick Videos</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="#a" data-type="internal" data-id="#a">1121a Bruchgleichungen Einführung und erstes Beispiel</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Videos</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:group --><div id="a" class="wp-block-group">
<!-- wp:embed {"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnQSWajcbj8","type":"video","providerNameSlug":"youtube","responsive":true,"className":"wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-block-embed-youtube wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnQSWajcbj8
</div></figure><!-- /wp:embed -->
</div><!-- /wp:group -->
```

Is there something that I am not taking into account with the code or is there a fix to the difference in viewing based on editing status.